# How can we get randomly selected text and image in javascripton on mouseup from page?

Tags: javascript

I want to get selected text and image on a mouse event.  I've tried `window.getSelection()` but this will return only selected text not images.

Can someone help me understand how I can get the selected image in JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

At first I thought this would be a [duplicate of this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139616/window-getselection-gives-me-the-selected-text-but-i-want-the-html), but then again, the other question doesn't show how to select the nodes from the selection.

`window.getSelection()` will give you the selection, but *not* the *current* (or highlighted) selection. You need to use the selection's `getRangeAt` method for that

```
var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
```

which will give you the range object (refer [DOM Range](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Traversal-Range/ranges.html)) of currently selected item(s). In this Range object, there are `startContainer`, `endContainer`, and `commonAncestorContainer`, which will give you the DOM node of whatever you're selecting. Note that for text, it will mean text nodes, of which its parent might be a `p` node.
If you read the first link, you will know that you can also extract it out of the document, or you can clone the selection and modify it without touching the original.

But if you want to edit-in-place what is in the selection, you may have to traverse through the nodes in the selection by yourself. If the image you select is at the beginning or the end of the selection, it is easy to get it: just use either `startContainer` or `endContainer`. But things get tricky when you have image between blocks of text.