# Remove <font> with specific color from DOM fragment

Tags: javascript, html

Here is the DOM fragment

[image]

which I am getting using :

```
var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
var selectionContents = range.cloneContents();
console.log(selectionContents) // <-- it displays DOM fragment from selection.
```

I want to remove the `<font color="#0000ff">&nbsp;Smith</font>`.

[image]

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: Do you want to remove it entirely, or simply unwrap it (i.e. `&nbsp; Smith` will be moved out of the `<font>` tag)?

Comment: Please do not post images, but the actual code, to make it easy to copy.

Comment: @Terry : I want to remove the font with `color="#0000ff"` entirely

Comment: do you want to only remove the color or remove the whole line

Comment: so you want to remove text with that color? like if the word is colored #0000ff then remove word?

Comment: Could you describe your use case? Your approach seems like a complicated way to change the color of some text on the page. Maybe there is a simpler way.

Comment: Will you do something with DOMFragment afterward? Don't you want to remove the original node instead of the cloned one?

Comment: @Kaiido: Yes, i'll extract and append the new one. I just created this example to keep it simple. I'll work on that now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove the `<font>` element with the specific `color` attribute of `#0000ff`, then you can simply search for the element iteratively within the `selectionContents` node, and then remove the node if it matches your criteria:

```
var fontEls = selectionContents.querySelectorAll('font');
fontEls.forEach(function(fontEl) {
  if (fontEl.color === '#0000ff')
    fontEl.remove();
});
```

See proof-of-concept below (and check your console):

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
  var selectionContents = range.cloneContents();
  
  var fontEls = selectionContents.querySelectorAll('font');
  fontEls.forEach(function(fontEl) {
    if (fontEl.color === '#0000ff')
      fontEl.remove();
  });
  
  console.log(selectionContents);
});
```

```html
<div>
  There, <b>Samuel<font color="#0000ff">&nbsp;Smith</font><font color="#ff0000">&nbsp;Smith</font><font color="#00ff00">&nbsp;Smith</font></b>
</div>
<button type="button">Get selection</button>
```

Comment: Many thank Terry. Can I ask your opinion abt manipulating the selected DOM. from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139616/window-getselection-gives-me-the-selected-text-but-i-want-the-html/#answer-2139792 , I can see that I can extract the selected `DOM` but to append I need to create a new `div` and append. Can I not simply remove the `font` and append the result. I dont want to add new `div` everytime

Comment: @Samuel If that's the case, make a `<div>` in the markup and give it an id, e.g. `<div id="output">`. Whenever you fetch the `selectionContent`, simply set the `#output` inner HTML to it. Then you don't create a new element every time.