# Getting list of <span> elements in a Selection() object

Tags: javascript, textselection

Given HTML like:

```
<p>
    <span id="text 1"> Hey everyone </span>
    <span id="text 2"> I have a</span>
    <span id="text 3"> question for you.</span>
</p>
```

and a selection from "everyone" to "have", I can get a Selection object by:

```
function GetSelectedNodes() {
    if (window.getSelection) {
        var selection = window.getSelection();
        var start_node = selection.anchorNode;
        var end_node = selection.focusNode;
    }
 }
```

But what I want is a list of the Span elements in the selection. How do I get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).cloneContents();
```

Source - [window.getSelection() gives me the selected text, but I want the HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139616/window-getselection-gives-me-the-selected-text-but-i-want-the-html)